# Spring binding showing new data not old

Tags: spring-mvc, binding

Sorry but I'm new to spring. But I have an issue where there are fields from two tables on my jsp. When an optimistic lock error been created.

I have two browser open with the same data. On screen one I add a record to table B. I then save this. Then screen redisplays with a saved correctly message.
On the second browser I alter some fields from Table A and click the save button. After the optimistic lock error has been thrown, the screen redisplays. The fields from table A are the original ones I changed on browser two. But the fields from Table B include the new one entered on browser one.

We are trying to show the user what the values were when they clicked save. So dont want to see the new record written to table B at this point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your controller, after an error, is returning a new View to the user and reading the entity again. Perhaps you redirect to a GET that displays the form?

If you have a controller method that catches any errors (validation or otherwise), rather than returning a Model and View (where the new model replaces the original values, you can just return a view (the same view the POST came from) and it should display the values as edited by the user.

Something like this...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getForm() {
    // Get the model data...
    MyModel model = ...
    return new ModelAndView(VIEW_NAME, MODEL_NAME, model);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView handlePost(@ModelAttribute(MODEL_NAME) MyModel model,
                               BindingResult errors) {
    ModelAndView mav = null;

    // Process/validate...
    if (has errors)  {
        // possibly add something to errors
        mav = new ModelAndView(VIEW_NAME);
    else {
        // new view instead...
    }

    return mav;
}
```

Comment: Yes the controller is reading the data again. It reads the current state them binds the forms values over the top. But then adds any new items too. I have had to rebuild the objects again from the request parameters. I just hoped there was a better way for this to be done.